# Send image from localstore to mysql with ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to send a picture stored in localstore with javascript but can't retrieve it and show it.

Javascript part :

```
liste['pic'] = localStorage['pic'];

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "save.php",  
                data: { pic : liste['pic'] },
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data) {
                        alert("Picture sent succesfully");
                    }
                }  
                });
```

The php part that receive the data :

```
require "lib/connect.php";
$pic = $_POST['pic'];
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO liste ( `pic` ) VALUES ( '".$pic."' );";
$result = mysql_query($insert_query);
```

The php part that shows the pic.
There's something in the table but since it's blob , I can't check if the right data.

```
$select_query = "Select   `pic` From liste;";
$result = $dbhandle->query($select_query);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><img src=\"" . $row['pic'] . "\" width=\"200\"/><br/><br/></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
$result->closeCursor();
mysqli_close($dbhandle);
```

from this I get a broken image. What is missing ? Text works but not image, why ?

Comment: Maybe the image data is getting corrupted? Have you tried to do base64_encode before sending the ajax request? You would need to do base64_decode when you retrieve the data from db...

Comment: you should log the variable every step of the way to see where it's getting lost.  use console.log in the script before the ajax.  firephp, or file_put_contents in the php part, and in the html you can just look at the page source to see what it's inserting in the img tag. that should at least give you an idea where the problem is occuring.

Comment: localStorage['pic'] is it the path of image or image blob data ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to know is that when you are sending values encoded in `json` through `POST`, these values are not present in the `$_POST` variables.

The only way to have values in the POST variables is by using having the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.

If you wish to use another content-type, you actually need to use `'php://input'`.

e.g.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$text = print_r($data, true);
```

You should then see an array containing your image's data.